# Specify Order for DriveApp getFilesByType

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When I use DriveApp getFilesByType it provides me a huge number of files.

I want to know if I call it multiple times if the results will always return in the same order? Or if there is a way to specify the order?

Or should I retrieve all documents then order them in AppsScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to control the order returned in Apps Script, and we don't guarantee an explicit or stable order. If you want them ordered you will have to do that in Apps Script code after you have retrieved them.

Comment: The problem is that if it's too many files one will hit the "execution time" quota before they can loop through all files, even without doing any action.

Comment: Please file a feature request around ordering and we'll see what's possible.

Comment: Additionally, you can use the full set of Drive SDK search parameters in DriveApp.find(), so you may be able to limit your result set to only files that would meet your sorting. https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

Comment: I've opened this feature request a while ago, here: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2834